# Problem Finding a Determinant - Wrong Answer

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem:

Find the given determinant:

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
6 & -7 & -6 & -5  \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2  \\
\end{vmatrix}
Answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Let}\,\,\, D =
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
6 & -7 & -6 & -5  \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2  \\
\end{vmatrix}
&=&
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
6 & -7 & -6 & -5  \\
0 & -3 & -3 & -9  \\
0 & -3 & -4 & -3  \\
\end{vmatrix}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
D &=&
\begin{vmatrix}
-7 & -6 & -5 \\
-3 & -3 & -9 \\
-3 & -4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
- 3
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -6 & -5 \\
0 & -3 & -9 \\
0 & -4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ 4
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -7 & -5 \\
0 & -3 & -9 \\
0 & -3 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
- 5
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -7 & -6 \\
0 & -3 & -3 \\
0 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-7 & -6 & -5 \\
-3 & -3 & -9 \\
-3 & -4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}   &=&
-7 \begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -9 \\
-4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix} + 6 \begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -9 \\
-3 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
- 5 \begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -3 \\
-3 & -4 \\
\end{vmatrix} = -7(9-36) + 6(9-27) - 5(12-9) \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-7 & -6 & -5 \\
-3 & -3 & -9 \\
-3 & -4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}   &=& -7(-27) + 6(-18) -5(3)  = 7(27) - 6(18) - 15 = 66 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -6 & -5 \\
0 & -3 & -9 \\
0 & -4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix} &=& 6
\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -9 \\
-4 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 6(9-36) = -6(24) = -144 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -7 & -5 \\
0 & -3 & -9 \\
0 & -3 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix} &=&
6
\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -9 \\
-3 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 6(9-27) = -6(18) = -108 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -7 & -6 \\
0 & -3 & -3 \\
0 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{vmatrix} &=&
6
\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -3 \\
-3 & -4 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 6(12 - 9) = 18 \\
D &=& 66 - 3(-144) + 4(-108) - 5(18) = 66 + 3(144) - 4(108) - 5(18) \\
D &=& -24 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

According to Scilab the correct value for this determinant is $30$.
Therefore, I conclude that I am wrong and I am hoping somebody will tell
me where I went wrong.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: $9-36=-\color{red}{27}$  (You might want to expand along column 1 instead of row 1.)

Comment: Why not expand along row $4$ ?

Comment: Peter, it would have been easier if I had done that but I did not think of it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
6 & -7 & -6 & -5  \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2  \\
\end{vmatrix}

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
0 & -25 & -30 & -35  \\
0 & -3 & -3 & -9  \\
0 & -3 & -4 & -3  \\
\end{vmatrix}

$$
15 
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & -3 & -4 & -3 
\end{array}
\right|
$$

$$
15 
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -8 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 6 
\end{array}
\right|
$$

$$
15 
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -8 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 
\end{array}
\right|
$$

$$
-15 
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 
\end{array}
\right|
$$

$$
30 
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}
\right|
$$

Comment: In addition to being a good answer, bravo for writing it out!